# Powermail - Error "No form to show"

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

I recently made an update from TYPO3 6.2 to TYPO3 7.6
I updated all my extensions but Powermail isn't running well : in front-end I get a "No form to show" message.

All my old powermail datas (sent emails, forms, answers) are still available but no way to display my contact form to my visitors.

My Powermail is 4.4.0.
In the module, tab "Function check", all is GREEN.

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Just test with original HTML-Templates (and Partials) and without any extensions that extends powermail. The error should be solved with this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably had an older version of powermail where all the tablenames ended with an "s" like :

- tx_powermail_domain_model_answers
- tx_powermail_domain_model_fields
- ...

By updating the extension you created another set of tables (empty) with no "s" at the end of the tablenames:

- tx_powermail_domain_model_answer
- tx_powermail_domain_model_field
- ...

I suggest you move the content of the older tables to the new ones.

Answer (score -1):

Did you update Powermail?
Powermail has an update-wizard too, it's located in an own modul for Powermail.
There you can update existing forms, just lose access to old mails then from the backend.
Probably you've to update some templates too, it's mentioned in the manual related to updates.

Powermail is a bit annoying for updates because there have been at least 2 table-changes where one never had been required.

So try the wizard first, if that's not working you've to follow through all the update messages.

EDIT:
**After executing the Update-Wizard of Powermail**

- Check the main-template for includes of powermail, names and locations might have changed, therefore you've to include the new template again.
- check all plugins of powermail, names of the plugin changed and you've to adjust the plugin again
- Afterwards you might have to clear all caches by the button in install-tool.

Comment: I made all the "Upgrade Wizard" function, and all the "Database analyzer" queries.

Comment: @Paolito75 added more details in the answer

Comment: Any Down-Voters: Please correct me if something is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: it didn't work then I gave up the idea to upgrade 6.2 -> 7.6. I'm going to install a new fresh 7.6 website and migrate manually all my contents.